# Combine Azure Mobile App with Azure Web App including Authentification

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

How can code between Azure Mobile APP and Azure Web APP can be shared?
Are there any disadvantages when merging both apps into one application?
Can authentification be shared between these two platforms?
Let's say, the Web App makes login possible using user name and password (no social providers!) and the mobile app makes possible both (user name + password AND social providers).
Do I need Azure B2C?

Comment: ``merging both apps into one application`` You'd like to merge two apps into one application, do Azure Mobile APP and Azure Web APP have similar functionality (or provide similar functionality for other services/clients)? Would' you like to merge two app into one project as one app or publish one of them as main app and make another one as virtual application?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely merge both apps.  There are caveats as normal.  This case is covered in the ZUMO Book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - around chapter 6.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages? How do you handle authentification?

Comment: What do I have to choose? Azure Web App or Azure Mobile App. Do both of them support all features? Are they really identical?

Comment: These questions are all covered in the book.  Please review the provided material before asking questions!